# Get total count of rows in pagination query

Tags: sql, oracle, pagination, oracle10g

I have the following query for record pagination

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT e.*, 
               ROWNUM row_num
          FROM (SELECT emp_no,
                       emp_name,
                       dob 
                  from emp) outr
          WHERE ROWNUM < ( (pagenum * row_size) + 1))
 WHERE  row_num >= ( ( (pagenum  - 1) * row_size) + 1)
```

I would like to get the count of rows as well in same query and for this I have tried 
using

```
COUNT(*) OVER ()
```

however I am not getting accurate results when I am paginating to next set of page and rows.

How can I use `COUNT(*) OVER ()` efficiently?

Comment: Please provide sample of data and desired output.

Comment: You should place the COUNT(*) in the innermost query: `SELECT emp_no, emp_name, dob, COUNT(*) FROM emp`. Of course, this way you'll have to count all the rows everytime you fetch the records for the next page. I suppose you don't want to fetch the number of the rows once?

Comment: @PrzemyslawKruglej Could you kindly explain what exactly you meant by  **I suppose you don't want to fetch the number of the rows once?**

Comment: What I meant is to first fetch the number of the rows, and do not do it again - keep the value. Of course, this way you may fail to show some the records that could be added while the user is going through the pages of results, but if the table from which you fetch the data is large, counting the records every time may impact performance.

Comment: @PrzemyslawKruglej Yes now I got your point. Thanks. So if table is large, `count(*) over ()` would have impact on performance isn't it? So best solution is by doing in two separate queries?

Comment: Hm, I'm actually confused a bit right now after doing some reading, would have to check if what I say is true, sorry for any misunderstanding. Maybe someone with more experience than me could shed some light onto the issue. I recommend the following article: [Thomas Kyte's article in Oracle Magazine](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-sep/o56asktom-086197.html).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A typical pagination query with the total number of rows would be:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT outr.*,
               ROWNUM row_num
          FROM (SELECT emp_no,
                       emp_name,
                       dob,
                       count(*) over () total_nb
                  FROM emp
                 ORDER BY ...) outr
         WHERE ROWNUM < ((pagenum * row_size) + 1))
 WHERE row_num >= (((pagenum - 1) * row_size) + 1)
```

Don't forget the `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Vincent, By using `count(*) over ()` does has any impact on performance?

Comment: compared to what? compared to not having the total, sure: you ask Oracle to retrieve the count so it basically has to fetch all rows. Compared to another method? well this will probably perform nicely in most cases, I guess it would depend upon the other method.

Comment: I used to have two different sql queries, one to fetch the records and another to have count of rows. So I was wondering to use one query to get all records and count of rows.

Comment: In most cases, running one query should outperform running the two independent queries, but not by much since the amound of work is approximately the same.

Comment: This should be tested because I tried a 2nd query just for count vs this and running two separate queries runs alot faster. Just try it out.