# single SQL query with total records and pagination

Tags: sql, pagination, web-sql, ansi-sql

I've a query that pulls records based on the search parameter, and I want query to return total records as well as paginate based on start and end, do I've to run two queries or is there more intuitive way to do in a single query.

```
SELECT * FROM page WHERE article_id = ? AND content like '%@%' //replacing @ with keyword
```

Edit:
Looking for Standard SQL (using WebSQL actually)

Comment: Will depend largely on the DBMS you're using

Comment: I'm using websql so pretty much wanna stay inside standard sql

Comment: There isn't a "standard" way of paginating results

Comment: I'm pretty sure SQLLite is the only database server used by anyone who implemented WebSQL.  SQLLite does have a LIMIT and OFFSET that you can use. There's any number of threads here on SO that have what your looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14468586/efficient-paging-in-sqlite-with-millions-of-records

Answer (score 0):

This query will return for each row the total of records and the actual page (considering there is 5 rows per page)

```
select *, count(*) as total, (seq - MOD(seq, 5)) / 5
from (select id, row_number() over(order by id) as seq
      from page) a
join page b on b.id = a.id;
```

Note that this query will works only for `Oracle` since you did not specify your `DBMS` I decided by myself so you might have to edit.

Comment: actually i did mention some comments on it, looking for standard sql, editing my question, can you please help me adopt this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19378892/get-total-count-of-rows-in-pagination-query

Comment: @user3610227: that **is** "standard SQL" (except for the `mod()` maybe)

Comment: I can't, it has functions which I don't have a clue on, for instance `over` and `row_number`, I'm looking for a websql based solution, possible please, error `could not prepare statement (1 near "(": syntax error)"`

Answer (score -1):

Try to use a subquery

```
count * from table where (select .....)
```

Comment: Thanks, I found a link but unable to understand so far, can you please help in that perspective http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19378892/get-total-count-of-rows-in-pagination-query